# Angular2 Karma+Jasmine A platform with a different configuration has been created

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-services

I have the following weird issue.
I am testing Angular 2.1.0 app with karma 1.3 and jasmine for unit testing. Everything works fine, but sometimes I got an error **A platform with a different configuration has been created.** This is messing with other testing features.

I have found out it depends on testing module's services and providers. I have this code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpModule],
        providers: [MyService, HttpService]
    });
});
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
}
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private http: HttpService) {
    }
}
```

With this code it throws that error. BUT if there is no dependency to external library (like http), the error disappears.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

However, the rest of the application works fine. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: At any point did you happen to call `TestBed.initTestInvironment`?

Comment: Yep, I used this project template: https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/blob/master/karma-shim.js

Comment: Nah that is fine. I thought maybe you were calling it in your tests